# Capturing Document Level Keypress Events in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a toy application that simulates a typing training program that I'm trying to build in angularjs.  I have been unable to use ng-keypress successfully in any template so I have had to attach it to the body tag in the layout.  This feels a little awkward but nothing else seems to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='TypingTrainer'>
<head>
  <title>Typing Trainer</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all'%>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', controller_name %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'main' %> 
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body ng-keypress="$broadcast('my:keyup', $event)">

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

In the controller for I call this function.  The listen function moves the cursor and changes the color of the letter to red if you typed an incorrect letter.

```
   $scope.$on "my:keyup", (event, keyEvent) ->
    console.log(keyEvent)
    $scope.listen(keyEvent)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `div` setting the `tabindex` attribute to zero:

```
<div tabindex="0" ng-keypress="$broadcast('my:keyup', $event)">
  ...
</div>
```

That's also a hack, but seems to work.